# Groovy script is not working in Jenkins Active choice parameter

Tags: groovy, parameters, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am working a groovy script which is working perfectly on the Jenkins Scriptler but when I tried to run the same script from active choice parameter, it is not returning any values.

Could someone help me on this?

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
exception_file = "test/10-01-2023/test"
String ex_date = exception_file.split('/')[1].toString()
println ex_date
cDate = java.time.LocalDate.now()
currentDate = cDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"))
expiry_date = Date.parse("dd-MM-yyyy", ex_date)
return expiry_date
```

But in parameters it is empty. AM i missing something?

Comment: double return??

Comment: my bad, its only one

Comment: Where do you get `exception_file` from? You are missing `def` in front of variable definitins, e. g. `def cDate =`, `def currentDate =`, `def expiry_date =`. Actually the last one is superfluous as you could just do `return Date.parse("dd-MM-yyyy", ex_date)`.

Comment: @zett42, I need to use the expiry_date variable later on. but this code is working fine in scriptler, but not in the ```active_choice_parameter```.

Comment: i have updated the actual code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reproduced the problem using your code. The only thing you are missing is the correct return type. It must be either `java.util.List`, `Array`, or `java.util.Map`.

In the following I'm returning an array.

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
exception_file = "test/10-01-2023/test"
String ex_date = exception_file.split('/')[1].toString()
println ex_date
cDate = java.time.LocalDate.now()
currentDate = cDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"))
expiry_date = Date.parse("dd-MM-yyyy", ex_date)
return [ expiry_date ]
```

This renders like:

[image: ActiveChoice parameter]